# number of ways to cover an $m × n$ rectangle

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, tiling

Given a positive integer $k\ge2$, let be $f_k(m,n)$  the number of ways to cover an $m × n$ rectangle with $mn/k$ tiles ( $1×k$ or $k×1$)

$f_2(m,n)$ is kasteleyn formula

$f_k(m,n)$?

Comment: I'm sure there's no known exact formula (analogous to Fischer-Temperley/Kasteleyn) for this.

Comment: Although, if say $m$ (and $k$) are fixed, then by standard techniques $f_k(m,n)$ as a function of $n$ satisfies a linear recurrence with constant coefficients, so its generating function is rational, etc.